# Distribute data into two columns

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I am trying to find out the best-optimized way of splitting alternative rows of a  column into two column. Let me explain this by an example

**I have the following data**

[image: Source]

**Resultset I want**

[image: Resultset]

in the above example, the alternative row is shifted to a new column.I have come up with a solution but it is not optimized if I have millions of records.

**My Solution (Not optimized)**

```
;WITH RecCtea
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) rowid FROM tabA ta  
)
SELECT a.cola,b.cola FROM (
(SELECT * FROM RecCtea rc WHERE rc.rowid%2 = 0) a JOIN 
 (SELECT * from RecCtea rc2 where rc2.rowid%2 != 0) b
 on a.rowid = b.rowid+1
 )
```

**SQLfiddle** is not working so here is the schema

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tabA (
> cola int 
> );
>
>
> INSERT tabA
> (
>     cola
> )
> VALUES
> (100),(-100),(200),(-250),(300),(-350),(-400),(NULL)
> ```

Comment: Are you saying the alternative value is always a negative number? And/or always inserted after its parent? Or that there is a consistency in the increased ABSOLUTE value of the column? Or just an example and you postulate using ROW_NUMBER() to solve it

Comment: @clifton_h no, it might be a positive or a negative value. I just want row number 1,3,5,7... in one column and 2,4,6,8... in another

Comment: So there is no concern for the order of say Col_Odd and Col_Even?

Comment: yes, there is the order of the column matters. In my solution if I use select 1 with row_number it changes the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [0] AS col1, [1] AS col2
FROM 
(
  SELECT cola, 
         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) + 1) / 2 AS rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) % 2 rowid 
  FROM tabA 
) AS src
PIVOT (
   MAX(cola) FOR rowid IN ([0],[1])) AS pvt
```

**Output:**

```
col1    col2
------+------
-100  | 100
-250  | 200
-350  | 300
NULL  | -400
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks but why did you used 

(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) + 1) / 2 AS rn,

Comment: @ankitsuhail I used it so as to group together consecutive rows. You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER` and then consume this value by the `src` derived table. I may perform a bit faster.

Comment: @Giogos Any place where I can read about PIVOT behaviour like what is happening here ? As I had never came across such a great thing.

Comment: @ankitsuhail Have a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with conditional aggregation , `CASE EXPRESSION` , `ROUND` and `ABS`, no need for window functions/pivoting :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.cola < 0 THEN t.cola END) as cola_minus,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.cola > 0 THEN t.cola END) as cola_plus
FROM (SELECT s.cola,ABS(ROUND(t.cola/100)) as group_number
      FROM TabA s) t
GROUP BY t.group_number
```

Each group will get a new value `group_number` which is the absolut result of the round of `cola/100` . Then it will group by it, and use the conditional aggregation to Pivot them.

Comment: it is not necessary that every alternative number will not be a negative number, although it is my fault that I gave such a data but nice solution. Another concern is that using ABS, Round, Max , Min might be degrading the performance when we are talking about million records. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I believe they will be faster then `ROW_NUMBER()` , but hard to tell :) @ankitsuhail

Comment: actually you are right on this one. I'll test it with a huge table and post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rn,
        cola
FROM tabA
)

SELECT  c2.cola,
        c1.cola
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.rn = c2.rn-1
WHERE c1.rn%2 = 1 AND c2.rn%2 = 0
```

Output:

```
cola    cola
-100    100
-250    200
-350    300
NULL    -400
```

Comment: Just a habit, in this case you can use INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN.